# Error: Could not find or load main class VM

Tags: java

Got a strange error during launching an app from idea.

```
/Users/me/work/tomcat-8.5/bin/catalina.sh run
[2018-01-22 12:49:16,300] Artifact myapp:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Error: Could not find or load main class VM
Disconnected from server
```

Comment: You really should try giving us some more intel, because so far, there are too many things that could have gone wrong!

Comment: Thanks for reply, problem was on wrong VM options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in copy-pasting VM options in Run configuration dialog.

Wrong options

```
VM options -Xms3024m -Xmx4000m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.timezone=UTC
```

Correct

```
-Xms3024m -Xmx4000m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.timezone=UTC
```

Comment: Cool thanks, I had a similar problem was missing the -